# How do I set the docker volume in ecs?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, volume, aws-fargate

I'm going to transfer what I worked on the previous EC2 to the ECS.

In traditional EC2, the `-v /home/ubuntu:/data` option allowed the volume to be set.

First, I added volume through "Volume add in task definition" and proceeded with mounting as before.

However, this did not produce a normal result.

So I have some concerns.

For Ubuntu, it's the `/home/ubuntu` path, but I'm not sure how the ECS Fargate path is configured.

Secondly, I am wondering if adding `:/data` at the end of the container path is the right way.

[Defined Volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G43i.png)

[Volume set to existing EC2 written in JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLwIf.png)

[Mount Points in ECS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnd8J.png)

Comment: Does this help : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-volumes.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Fargate you would need to use an [EFS volume](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-mount-efs-containers-tasks/) for this. You don't have access to host volumes with Fargate.